# How to implement XMPP in My VB.Net Application

Tags: vb.net, xmpp, ejabberd

I am Newbie in XMPP . I want to create chat application in VB.net using XMPP .
i am having ejabberd serverin  my pc.
i dont know how to intract with ejabberd server via VB.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how XMPP works, but am not sure how to connect your application to your XMPP server, you can start with a .NET library that handles all XMPP interaction for you. Jabber-net is one of them. http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/

I've used this library pretty extensively on a project, and it's quite useful - Given that you know how XMPP works.

One thing to note is that it is written in C# - But it doesn't prevent you from reference the DLL in your VB.net project.

Comment: thanks Dashk,I am already have this protocol.but i dont knw how  to  start with this.help me to code..

Comment: There's a VB example in Jabber-Net: http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/VB.Example/MainForm.vb